# Ubuntu 15.04 not using swap

Tags: partitioning, mount, 15.04, swap

I am running Ubuntu 15.04 on my Dell laptop.

For some reason Ubuntu is not using swap.

The swap partition is created:

```
Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048     718847     716800   350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          718848  212721663  212002816 101.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       212721664  422436507  209714844   100G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       422436864 1953523711 1531086848 730.1G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       422438912  439216127   16777216     8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       439218176 1953523711 1514305536 722.1G 83 Linux
```

`fstab` looks like this:

```
/dev/sda3       /       ext4    errors=remount-ro       0       1
/dev/sda5       none    swap    defaults                0       0
/dev/sda6       /data   ext4    errors=remount-ro       0       0
```

`mount -l | grep sda` only displays these

```
/dev/sda3 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/sda6 on /data type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
```

Running `swapon` makes no difference.

`free -h` display this:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7.7G       5.4G       2.3G       156M       533M       1.2G
-/+ buffers/cache:       3.7G       4.0G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: I am not sure, but you seem to have messed up something in your fstab. In my Ubuntu 15.04 installation the entries are UUID based, not device name based. In any case, as indicated below, the fourth option should be "sw", not "defaults". Although I don't know whether this should cause any trouble.

Comment: @errikos yes that is probably it. Just to make it sure: it needs to be "none" "swap" "sw" "0" "0"

Comment: That is correct, this is what it looks like now: UUID=ee482d21-82e2-4666-aad2-07e4a9d14416 none swap sw 0 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it does want a UUID

Recreated with: **sudo mkswap /dev/sda5**

Added to fstab: **UUID=ee482d21-82e2-4666-aad2-07e4a9d14416 none swap sw 0 0**

Run: **sudo swapon --all**

Checked with: **sudo free**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       8077992    6407896    1670096     201436     249436     905480
-/+ buffers/cache:    5252980    2825012
Swap:      8388604          0    8388604
```

Now it is working

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is the total - 0GB, the only difference I could find is that on my (Fedora) system `fstab` looks like this:

```
/dev/mapper/fedora-swap  swap  swap  defaults  0  0
```

The `/dev` part is different because I use LVM, the difference is in the second parameter, at you that is none, here is `swap`

Comment: He is probably more concerned about the "total" being size 0 for swap.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right, changed my answer